# Docker compose push to registry with Spring and mysql image

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I'm new with docker-compose, i've created one that work good in my local default machine:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql-docker-container:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=*****
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=*****
      - MYSQL_USER=*****
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=*****
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - /data/mysql
    restart: always
  myproject-server-container:
    image: myproject
    build:
      context: ./
      args:
        JAR_FILE: target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mysql-docker-container
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    volumes:
      - /data/server
    restart: always
```

Now I need to push application with the mysql images to a remote registry.
When I had just my project image without database container I simply did `docker tag "imageId" "repo/myimageName"` then `docker push repo/myimageName`.

Now how could I do the same with a docker-compose file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're using a public mysql image, you don't need to push that. You can just push your application image.

Should you want to also push the mysql image to your own private repository, you can do that by executing `docker-compose push` which will attempt to push all images.

Assuming you're hosting your own registry at example.com, you just need to set that as part of your image name in order to have the image go there instead of Docker hub.

```
version: '3'
services:
  service1:
    build: .
    image: example.com/yourimage  # goes to example.com registry

  service2:
    build: .
    image: youruser/yourimage  # goes to youruser DockerHub registry
```

See the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/push/) for more options and examples

Comment: Thanks for answer, but where I need to put the registry url?

Comment: See updated answer, you just include the url of the registry in the image name.

Comment: Ok perfect, I already read that answer and I did so but I received errors from registry. I'll check with registry owner, probably the register service it's down.